# How do I log the output of my SFTP command

Tags: unix, logging, sftp, eof

This is a small snippet of code from a larger script I'm having difficulties with:

```
sftp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "IdentifyFile=/export/home/myid/.ssh/id_rsa" data_cc@111.222.333.444 <<EOF
put  /u01/myfiles/file.zip
EOF
```

The above does the task fine but...
How do I log what the SFTP command is doing? I've tried various options but nothing seems to work.

e.g.

```
sftp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "IdentifyFile=/export/home/myid/.ssh/id_rsa" data_cc@111.222.333.444 > mysftp.log <<EOF
put  /u01/myfiles/file.zip
EOF
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you are seeing output when you run your command from the cmd-line (not in a shell script), then the output seems to be going to std-err, so capture that too, with `scp .... > ftp.log 2>&1 ...` . If you're not seeing any output, then you can only check the return status of the `scp` to determine if there was an error or not, so `if scp ... ; then echo "good run" > ftp.log else echo "error sftp" > ftp.log ; fi`.  Good luck.

Comment: thanks for responding...so is this not possible using sftp?

Comment: You can to the same with `sftp`, what @shellter does with `scp`.

Comment: Thank you for your response     ```sftp -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "IdentifyFile=/export/home/myid/.ssh/id_rsa" data_cc@111.222.333.444  > ftp.log 2>&1 <<EOF
put  /u01/myfiles/file.zip
EOF```  ...something like this?